# Replacing .or. statement with if inside a for loop

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am trying to replace an `.or.` statement with an `if` statement inside a `do` loop. But when using the second method, I am not getting the result in first method.
Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

```
do j =1,115
   if (positions(i,1) .eq. j) .or. positions(i,2) .eq. j)then
    write(24,201) 47, atoms(j,2),atoms(j,3),atoms(j,4)
   endif
enddo


do j =1,115
 do m =1,2
   if (int(positions(i,m)) .eq. j)then
    write(24,201) 47, atoms(j,2),atoms(j,3),atoms(j,4)
   endif
 enddo
enddo
```

Comment: Does this even compile? Please correct your code!

Comment: Is the use of `int` in the second statement intentional? Is `positions` a `real` or `integer` array?

Answer (score 1):

The two statements you provide are logically different (ignoring the conversion to `int` which only occurs in the second case):

- In the first snippet, you print a line if the first or the second condition is true, resulting in either one line of output or none.
- In the second case you perform two check which each could print to unit `24`. If both conditions are true, you get **two** lines of output.

If you want to simplify the first statement you could e.g. use `any`:

```
do j=1,115
  if ( any(positions(j,1:2) == j) ) then
    write(24,201) 47, atoms(j,2),atoms(j,3),atoms(j,4)
  endif
enddo
```

Note that I replaced `i` in the loop with the loop counter `j` since there is no indication that `i` could be defined. This is pure guesswork, of course.

Comment: What I want to do is to kind of automate the checking of .or. conditions using a loop. Is there a way to do it in either fortran or python?

Comment: You could `exit` the loop once the first condition is true.